# Should I follow up 1 week after an application after getting invitations to interviews elsewhere?

Tags: applications, email

I applied to several open positions online and so far have received invitations to two different job interviews (company A and B, both ~50 employees). While I'd work for them (currently about to finnish university) and I'm in need of a job, there is another job at company C (> 20k employees) which would be my first choice and out of all three positions I'm arguably matching C's requirements perfectly (as advertised) and my impression is that for me it would be more fun than actual work. So far they only received 3 applications (according to linked in).
I applied 8 days ago to company C but didn't hear anything back except for an automated email response that said they would contact me if they were interested.
I do acknowledge that a week is a short timeframe, but I'm getting in a 2nd round interview with company A and a first round interview with company B this week.
I'd be disappointed to accept an offer of A or B (because I need a job) and hearing back from C a week later. On the other hand, asking only 1 week later  might come across as nagging (or even pressuring).

I'd plan to send something like

> Dear XYZ,
>
> I'd like to ask about the status of my application because I have received positive feedback from applications elsewhere but your job offering interests me the most and I would really like to grab this opportunity to work in my dream job.
>
> Best,
> ABC

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: @gnat I didn't have an interview yet, so this is not what I'm asking.

Comment: Have A and B interviewed you or offered you a job yet ? If not, then there is no need to contact C within a week of applying for job at C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree with people saying it's a waste of time. Whenever I've interviewed people or received CVs, I value pro-activeness a great deal.

The potential employee who gets up off their metaphorical behind to follow-up is more likely to also do so in the work environment.

So, I'd definitely reach out. You could also try some LinkedIn Detective work to try and find who it is you should talk to and then blag your way to either getting their DDI or getting a call transferred to them - and simply say you are calling to follow up on your CV, you are very keen to work for the company (look at the company website, if you can reference some of the Company values or something unique to that company that makes you want to work for them - reference that) and you'd like to know when they can schedule an interview.

It's bold, some recruiters get off-put by people side-stepping *their process*, but my experience is that those types of people aren't the ones I want to work for and the type of person that respects initiative and drive are always a better fit.

Answer (score 5):

> I applied 8 days ago to company C but didn't hear anything back except
> for an automated email response that said they would contact me if
> they were interested.

While it likely won't hurt to follow up, it's pretty much a waste of time.

They indicated that they would get back to you if interested. They haven't even gotten back to you yet, you have no idea of their actual interest, so they are unlikely to speed up their process even if you ask. It might be different if you had already had an interview.

If they are interested, they will get back to you. If not, they won't.

You should proceed as if they are not interested and keep going forward with other companies. Once you get a real offer, then you should decide to either accept it, or reject it because you feel strongly about getting an offer from your preferred company and are willing to take a chance on yourself.

> I'd like to ask about the status of my application because I have
> received positive feedback from applications elsewhere but your job
> offering interests me the most and I would really like to grab this
> opportunity to work in my dream job.

Remember that while it's important to you that this may be your dream job, the potential employer doesn't care about that.

If you choose to prompt them, you might instead consider indicating why you would be a terrific fit for their job, rather than the fact that it's your dream job.

Answer (score 4):

It's unlikely to make a difference: Larger companies get 100s of applications a day and some of the processing is automated. It's a slow process and the note  (even if someone actually reads it) is not going the help much.

> On the other hand, asking only 1 week later might come across as nagging

It's a reasonable request since you actually have interviews lined up. Even if someone is slightly miffed you really nave nothing to lose here.

Answer (score 1):

That seems absolutely 100% fine to me, a week is a reasonable time to wait and you've explained in your mail why you're following up. Do it.